# I am trying to Understand Content-Security-Policy Frame Ancestors tag

Tags: security, ionic-framework, ionic3, content-security-policy

I am trying to display one of my sites in a iframe inside my IONIC app. I need to restrict my website from being iframed by other websites. I decided to go with the content-security-policy response header where

`Content-security-policy: frame-ancestors ${website-to-be-allowed}`

made sure only the websites mentioned could iframe my website however I needed my ionic app to iframe my website as well and Since Ionic apps are served as file system I am okay with giving access to all file system to iframe my website. When I added

`Content-security-policy: frame-ancestors ${website-to-be-allowed} filesystem`

as mentioned here,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

I tested on both my Android and IOS app and both threw the same error saying,
which says,

`Refused to display ${website} in a frame because an ancestor violates the following content security policy directive: "frame-ancestors filesystem"`

Here is the error that pops up [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb8rI.png)

Comment: "It did not work." — This isn't a useful description of what happened. What browsers did you test this in? What error messages were reported on the developer tool's consoles? What didn't it work for (the website you are allowing? the ionic app?)?

Comment: @quentin This is my first time asking a stackoverflow question, I have updated the question, Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Just for reference I got it working using:

`file://* filesystem:`

So the overall content security policy could look like this:

`Content-Security-Policy: "...; frame-ancestors 'self' file://* filesystem:;`

Answer (score 1):

You need the colon at the end of "filesystem".  Try

`frame-ancestors ${website-to-be-allowed} filesystem:`

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply. But unfortunately that didn't worth either :/ :(.